# Problem with accessing a variable from one class in another class (tkinter GUI - navigation bar)

Tags: class, oop, tkinter, navigationbar, class-variables

Im using this code to display a navigation-bar which lets me switch between the currently shown mainpage:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("600x400")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.mainframes = {}

        for F in (Mainframe1, Mainframe2):
            frame = F(container, self)
            frame.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nswe")
            self.mainframes[F] = frame

        navigationbar = NavigationbarFrame(container, self)
        navigationbar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")

        self.show_frame(Mainframe1)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.mainframes[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class NavigationbarFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="green")

        # self.mainframe1_self = app.mainframes[Mainframe1]
        # self.mainframe2_self = app.mainframes[Mainframe2]
        # tk.Button(self, text=self.mainframe1_self.pagename, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Mainframe1)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", pady=5, padx=10)
        # tk.Button(self, text=self.mainframe2_self.pagename, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Mainframe2)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", pady=5, padx=10)

        tk.Button(self, text="Page 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Mainframe1)).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", pady=5, padx=10) #to be removed
        tk.Button(self, text="Page 2", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Mainframe2)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", pady=5, padx=10) #to be removed

class Mainframe1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, bg="yellow")
        tk.Label(self, text="this is Page 1",bg="yellow").grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=20)
        self.pagename = "Page 1"

class Mainframe2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, bg="grey")
        tk.Label(self, text="this is Page 2", bg="grey").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.pagename = "Page 2"


app = App()
mainframe1_self = app.mainframes[Mainframe1]

print(app.mainframes)
print(mainframe1_self)
print(mainframe1_self.pagename)

app.mainloop()
```

Now I am trying to edit the buttons in the NavigationbarFrame() class. I want to access the text for the Buttons from the Classes Mainframe1(), Mainframe2() [see: the #outcommented code]

For some reason I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\....py", line 53, in <module>
    app = App()
  File "C:\Users\....py", line 19, in __init__
    navigationbar = NavigationbarFrame(container, self)
  File "C:\Users\....py", line 32, in __init__
    self.mainframe1_self = app.mainframes[Mainframe1]
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

Even though I have created the instance app = App().

In the print commands right above the app.mainloop() I showed how I accesed the pagename string from the class Mainframe1().

I really can't figure out, why I am not able to access it from my NavigationbarFrame() class. Can you help me troubleshooting?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: 
______________________________

As Bryan Oakley recommended, I have added the get_frame() function and edited the NavigationbarFrame() class. Everything is working perfectly fine!

Since I am planning to add more than just two buttons, I am now trying to create them with a For loop:

```
class NavigationbarFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="green") #ersetzt {Frame(parent)}

        y=0
        for F in controller.mainframes:
            mainframe = controller.get_frame(F)
            tk.Button(self, text=mainframe.pagename, command = lambda: controller.show_frame(F)).grid(row=y, column=0, sticky="w", pady=5, padx=10)
            y += 1
```

This unfortunatly leads me right to the next problem: 
Somehow both of my created buttons lead me to Page2. I don't understand the reason for this, because the first button should include:

```
command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Mainframe1)
```

and the second button should include:

```
command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Mainframe2)
```

Does anyone know where my mistake is?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: i will insert it into the post!

Comment: please don't completely change the question to a different topic. A good question should only ask one thing. There are many questions on this site related to creating buttons or commands in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

At the time that `App` is being constructed, `app` doesn't exist. Since you're using object-oriented code you shouldn't be relying on a global variable. And finally, your `NavigationbarFrame` shouldn't be trying to access the `mainframes` variable inside of `App`. Even though the way it's coded, it's a public variable, the other classes really shouldn't rely on that - it couples the pages too tightly to the controller.

Instead, you should have a method in `App` that returns a given frame for you. You can then use that method to get a reference to the other frames.

Start by defining `get_page` to be just like `show_frame`, but instead of showing the frame it returns it:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    ...

    def get_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.mainframes[cont]
        return frame
```

Finally, use this method to get the frame. Since `controller` is the instance of `App`, you would do it like this:

```
class NavigationbarFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="green")

        mainframe1 = controller.get_frame(Mainframe1)
        mainframe2 = controller.get_frame(Mainframe2)

        b1 = tk.Button(self, text=mainframe1.pagename, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Mainframe1))
        b2 = tk.Button(self, text=mainframe.pagename, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Mainframe2))

        b1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", pady=5, padx=10)
        b2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", pady=5, padx=10)
```

Comment: Its working perfectly! Thank you very much! Now I am trying to add the buttons with a for loop, but I am having some trouble with the command effect. I have edited the post to give some details. Maybe you also now my mistake there?